# Input Sampler in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

My understanding about InputSampler is that it gets data from record reader and samples keys and then creates a partition file in HDFS.

I have few queries about this sampler:
1) Is this sampling task a map task ?
2) My data is on HDFS (distributed across nodes of my cluster). Will this sampler run on nodes which has the data to be sampled?
3) Will this consume my map slots? 
4) Will the sample run simultaneously with the map tasks of my MR job ? I want to know whether it will affect time consumed by mappers by reducing the number of slots?

Answer (score 5):

I found that the InputSampler makes a seriously flawed assumption and is therefore not very helpful.

The idea is that it samples key values from the mapper input and then uses the resulting statistics to evenly partition the mapper output.  The assumption then is that the key type and value distribution are the same for the mapper input and output.  In my experience the mapper almost never sends the same key value types to the reducer as it reads in. So the InputSampler is useless.

In the few times where I had to sample in order to partition effectively, I ended up doing the sampling as part of the mapper (since only then did I know what keys were being produced) and writing the results out in the mapper's close() method to a directory (one set of stats per mapper).  My partitioner then had to perform lazy initialization on its first call to read the mapper-written files, assimilate the stats into some useful structure and then to partition subsequent keys accordingly.

Your only other real option is to guess at development time how the key values are distributed and hard-code that assumption into your partitioner.

Not very clean but it was the best I could figure.

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a long time ago, and many questions were left unanswered.

The only and most voted answer by @Chris does not really answer the questions, but gives an interesting point of view, though a bit too pessimistic and misleading in my opinion, so I'll discuss it here as well.

## Answers to the original questions

The sampling task is done in the call to `InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler)`. The call to this method is blocking, during which the sampling is done, in the same thread.

That's why you don't need to call `job.waitForCompletion()`. It's not a MapReduce Job, it simply runs in your client's process. Besides, a MapReduce job needs at least 20 seconds just to start, but sampling a small file only takes a couple of second.

Thus, the answer to all of your questions is simply "No".

### More details from reading the code

If you look at the code of the `writePartitionFile()`, you will find that it calls `sampler.getSample()`, who will call `inputformat.getSplits()` to get a list of all input splits to be samples.

These input formats will then be read sequentially to extract the samples. Each input split is read by a new record reader created within the same method. This means that your client is doing the reading and sampling.

Your other nodes are not running any "map" or other processes, they are simply serving HDFS the block data needed by your client for its input splits needed for sampling.

## Using Different key types between Map input and output

Now, to discuss the answer given by Chris. I agree that the InputSampler and TotalOrderPartitioner are probably flawed in some ways, since they are really not easy to understand and use ... But they ***do not*** impose key types to be the same between map input and output.

The InputSampler uses the job's InputFormat (and its RecordReader) keys to create the partition file containing all sampled keys. This file is then used by the TotalOrderPartitioner during the partitioning phase at the end of the Mapper's process to create partitions.

**The easiest solution is to create a custom RecordReader, for the InputSampler only, which performs the *same key transformation* as your Mapper**.

To illustrate this, let's say your dataset contains pairs of (char, int), and that your mapper transforms them into (int, int), by taking the character's ascii value. For example 'a' becomes 97.

If you want to perform total order partitioning of this job, your InputSampler would sample letters 'a', 'b', 'c'. Then during the partitioning phase, your mapper output keys will be integer values like 102 or 107, which wouldn't be comparable to 'a', 'g' or 't' from the partition-file for partition distribution. This is not consistent, and this is why it looks like the input and output key types are assumed to be the same, when using the same InputFormat for sampling and your mapreduce job.

So the solution is to write a custom InputFormat and its RecordReader, used only for the sampling client-side job, which reads your input file and does the same transformation from `char` to `int` before returning each record. This way the InputSampler will directly write the integer ascii values from the custom record reader to the partition-file, which maintain the same distribution, and will be usable with your mapper's output.

It's not so easy to grasp in a few lines of text explanation texts, but anybody interested in fully understanding how the InputSampler and TotalOrderPartitioner work should check out this page : http://blog.ditullio.fr/2016/01/04/hadoop-basics-total-order-sorting-mapreduce/

It explains in details how to use them in different cases.